# Angular update textarea field from component

Tags: angular

I have a textarea and I am trying to push an update to that field.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I am successfully getting my combobox to pass the selected item into dropdownSourceSelected.  From there I want to:
1) update the textarea field
2) clear the combobox value (return it to undefined so the placeholder returns

I cannot figure out how to do this.  I have seen references to using $scope but when I tried this I got an error about $scope being unknown.

```
table-widget.component.html
      <textarea vertical-align:top ng-model="filterSelection" readonly name="selectedfilters" cols = "50" rows = "1"></textarea>

table.component.ts
  public dropdownSourceSelected(selection: string): void  {
    if (this.filterSelection != '')
      this.filterSelection += '&';
    this.filterSelection += "source=";
    this.filterSelection += selection;
    console.log('filter selection: ', this.filterSelection);
  }
```

Comment: Which version of Angular is this?

Comment: We are using Angular 2

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
ng-model="filterSelection"
```

Needs to be this:

```
[(ngModel)]="filterSelection"
```

And FYI `$scope` is AngularJS (v1). AngularJS and Angular have **very** different syntax so any posts you find with solutions in AngularJS won't work in Angular.

To set a property in a nested component, use an @Input property in the component and set that property using property binding in the HTML. So something like this:

```
import { Component, OnChanges, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-star',
    templateUrl: './star.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./star.component.css']
})
export class StarComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() rating: number;
    starWidth: number;
    @Output() ratingClicked: EventEmitter<string> =
            new EventEmitter<string>();

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.starWidth = this.rating * 86 / 5;
    }

    onClick(): void {
        this.ratingClicked.emit(`The rating ${this.rating} was clicked!`);
    }
}
```

You then set the rating property like this:

```
                        <pm-star [rating]='product.starRating'
                            (ratingClicked)='onRatingClicked($event)'>
                        </pm-star>
```

Comment: after I make that change how do I reference the field from table.component.ts?  How do I take filterSelection that I built in table.component.ts and populate it in the textarea element of table-widget.component.html?  It is that link that I am completely missing.

Comment: I updated my answer. And if I may say ... it is *very* difficult to learn Angular by way of "guess and check" using odd bits of code found in stackoverflow. You will save LOTS of time on your project if you spend a few hours and really learn the basics of Angular. I have a course if you are interested.

Comment: I am appreciating how difficult it is to learn Angular.  I have picked up a bunch but this basic stuff of how pieces connect is kicking me.  I am definitely interested in a course or some tutorial that makes sense.

Comment: Here is one I did: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update It is about 5 hours long and covers all of the basics. You can sign up for a free week to watch at no charge.

Comment: Thank you - we have a pluralsight subscription so I am definitely going to follow that tomorrow.